# ActionController::ParameterMissing in BooksController#update param is missing or the value is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I'm trying to run through a rails guide (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) but I'm having an issue when trying to update a book:
[ActionController::ParameterMissing in BooksController#update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0Unv.png)

Here is my update and edit methods in the books controller:

```
  def edit
   @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
   @books = Book.find(params[:id])

   if @book.update(book_params)
    redirect_to @book
   else
    render 'edit'
   end
  end
```

also the book_params definition:

```
  private
   def book_params
    params.require(:books).permit(:author, :title)
  end
```

and here's the edit view form I'm using:

```
<%= form_for :book, url: book_path(@book), method: :patch do |f| %>
```

I'm not sure why this error is appearing as using essentially the same code for articles (as presented in the guide) works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The form is not correct, you have to add the book key before sending it.

```
<%= form_for :@book, url: book_path(@book), method: :patch do |f| %>
```

Comment: You mean '@book' instead of ':book' ? It gives the same error and in fact the guide mentions how you can use a symbol with the same name as the instance variable and get the same result.